# orchard cache module cache specific url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, module, orchardcms

I'm new one in orchard community and not very well know the system. 
So I have a question about cache module: Is there any possibility to cache specific url's for different users? Or this issue is not supported by this module?

May be somebody knows ready solutions for this issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't cache per user with Orchard.Cache, in fact it contains these lines in the request filter, which means that it won't cache content for authenticated users at all!

```
// don't return any cached content, or cache any content, if the user is authenticated
if (_workContext.CurrentUser != null) {
    Logger.Debug("Request ignored on Authenticated user");
    return;
}
```

If you have *specific* information you want to cache (e.g. data retrieved from a third party API, information generated by users doing specific actions etc), you might be better off writing a module which handles this for you - [Orchard's ICacheManager component is really easy to use](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/orchard-caching-by-time).

There is a ton of information about writing your own Orchard modules, both on StackOverflow and on the [project site](http://docs.orchardproject.net/).